# Magento 2: No such entity with customerId = '' when place an order

Tags: magento-2.1

I getting below error when place an order.
Error: No such entity with customerId =

The customer placed an order with their login account but it's not showing customers in error.

This error is throwing from the below file : 
**/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/BillingAddressManagement.php**

```
 public function assign($cartId, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address, $useForShipping = false)
        {
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
            $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
            $quote->removeAddress($quote->getBillingAddress()->getId());
            $quote->setBillingAddress($address);
            try {
            $quote->setDataChanges(true);
                $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
            /* check log file */
                $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/address-error.log');
                $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
                $logger->addWriter($writer);
                $logger->info('Billing - '.$cartId.' - '.$e->getMessage());
            /* log file over */
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                throw new InputException(__('Unable to save address. Please check input data.'));
            }
            return $quote->getBillingAddress()->getId();
        }
```

i have added below line for debug log :

```
$logger->info('Billing - '.$cartId.' - '.$e->getMessage());
```

so I getting below error while placing an order.

```
Billing - 8300 - No such entity with customerId =
```

Comment: have you get any solution ?

Comment: not getting any solution